# Huawei Mobile Services (HMS) exception: Token is invalid or expired when using ML kit Real-Time Translation on cloud?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-ml-kit

**exception:** Token is invalid or expired.

What is this error? I have already set the api key. And what does this token represent?

```
val setting: MLRemoteTranslateSetting =
                MLRemoteTranslateSetting.Factory()
                    .setSourceLangCode("en")
                    .setTargetLangCode("hu")
                    .create()
            val mlRemoteTranslator: MLRemoteTranslator =
                MLTranslatorFactory.getInstance().getRemoteTranslator(setting)

            try {
                val result = MLTranslateLanguage.syncGetCloudAllLanguages()
            } catch (e: MLException) {
                Log.e("ML exception", e.message.toString())
            }

            var output = ""
            try {
                output = mlRemoteTranslator.syncTranslate("SOURCE")
            } catch (e: MLException) {
                Log.e("ML exception", e.message.toString())
            }
            mlRemoteTranslator.stop()
```

I get this error here: `val result = MLTranslateLanguage.syncGetCloudAllLanguages()`
and here:  `output = mlRemoteTranslator.syncTranslate("SOURCE")`

I set the api key like this: `MLApplication.getInstance().apiKey = Utils.apiKey`

```
object Utils {

private const val TAG = "Utils"

@JvmStatic
val apiKey: String?
    get() {
        // get apiKey from AppGallery Connect
        val apiKey = "myApiKey"

        // need encodeURI the apiKey
        return try {
            URLEncoder.encode(apiKey, "utf-8")
        } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "encode apikey error")
            null
        }
    }}
```

Comment: The setting is correct. Could you please send your api key to hmscore@huawei.com for futher analyzation？You can also perform the configuration by referring to [Notes on Using Cloud Authentication Information](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/sdk-data-security-0000001050040129-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050750251__section2688102310166).

Comment: Thanks. I have sent my api key.

Comment: The length of your api key seems to be incorrect. It is recommended that you could delete the current application on the console and create a new application. Hope it helps! @Botond Sulyok

Comment: I did it, but unfortunately it doesn't help and the length of the API key is the same. @shirley

Comment: I didn't set an access token which may be a problem.
MLApplication.getInstance().setAccessToken("your access token") // but here I don't actually know what is this token for

Comment: You can [setApiKey](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/mlapplication-0000001050167420-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050167420__section165441628134218) instead of [setAccessToken](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/mlapplication-0000001050167420-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050167420__section191234171515).